# Não consigo acessar site hospedado no github

Tags: github

Coloquei o nome do meu repositório como **fingerstylebrasil.github.io** mas quando acesso ele aparece que a pagina nao existe, olhei nas configurações do repositório e aparece outro endereço, esse aqui: https://fmm312.github.io/fingerstylebrasil.github.io/, que consigo acessar o site normalmente, mas nao está como deveria, o correto seria ficar fingerstylebrasil.github.io (como está nomeado o nome do repositório)

quero saber como faço pra url do site ficar **github.io**

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível, pra que você use o domínio **github.io** o nome do repositório deve ser o mesmo do nome de usuário ou nome da organização, caso contrário o GitHub não "upará" seu site.

Como descrito na página **[User, Organization, and Project Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)** do GitHub Help

> You can only use your own account name for a User or Organization Page repository. A repository like joe/bob.github.io will not build a User Pages site.

Ou seja, funcionaria se seu nome de usuário fosse **fingerstylebrasil** ou se seu repositório se chamasse **fmm312.github.io**

Repositórios são sempre considerados como pastas quando não seguem esse padrão.